# "method must override or implement a superclass method" when I'm alreadying doing so

Tags: java, eclipse

I've seen this question asked many times, but the answers don't apply to me. Here is the offending interface:

```
public interface MapInterface<K, V> {

    public MapInterface<K, V> put(K key, V value);

}
```

And the class that implements this:

```
public class MapInterfaceImpl<K, V> implements MapInterface {

    @Override
    public MapInterface<K, V> put(K key, V value) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

I ignored irrelevant code. All the other similar questions point to java compiler compliance issue. They all said to change from 1.5 to 1.6. Since I'm using 1.8 since the beginning, that doesn't apply to me. So what's the issue here?

Edit: Just to add something. When Eclipse automatically adds the unimplemented methods from the interface, instead of `put(K key, V value)`, it writes `put(Object key, Object value)` instead. That is obviously different from the method signature in the interface, but the compiler doesn't give an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not overriding the contract of the interface, which has specified the generic parameters `<K, V>`.

You need to change your implements line to include that as well.

```
public class MapInterfaceImpl<K, V> implements MapInterface<K, V> {
    // implementation
}
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line:

`public class MapInterfaceImpl<K, V> implements MapInterface {`

with:

```
public class MapInterfaceImpl<K, V> implements MapInterface<K, V> {
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I picked Makoto's answer because his was posted first. Thank you again.